# is it possible to use embedded database like javadb or berkeley db in a google app engine app (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a scenario where a thesaurus has to be created. Instead of storing the thesaurus in datastore and accessing it everytime over the web, I am thinking of storing it in embdedded database like javadb, and the user can access the thesaurus through my web app while other sections of the same web app store data in google data store.

Is something like this doable? Are there any hurdles/pitfalls that I should be aware of, to implement this successfully? Or will I have to stick to google data store only?

Comment: what advantage do you hope to get by avoiding the datastore?

Comment: @PeterRecore- I have a requirement where a thesaurus will be extensively used- which means storage for the thesaurus (which is quite big) plus server side data access usage... If i shift this portion of the application (ie thesaurus only) to embedded database then that should lower costs, and functionality that I plan to offer is not affected in a bad way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this probably isn't possible. You can't write to the filesystem on App Engine, it might be possible if you're happy with the database being read-only, and the library you use to access it doesn't rely on native code.